# How can in filter by more than one value of same field at django admin using list_filter?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i have field "car" that contains values "Benz, Nissan, Kia"
using ==> list_filter ["car"] how can i filter by Both values like "Nissan" and "Kia" . Both not one of them

[Car objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjEoS.png)

Comment: You will search with a list from input or a select ?

Comment: at admin.py.

list_filter = ['car_model']

Comment: maybe you can find some insights here : https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135778/django-admin-change-list-filtering-multiple-manytomany

Answer (score 0):

You could use `MultipleChoiceListFilter` from [django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-multiple-choice-list-filter) package, since there is no multi-choice filter built into Django. Example:

models.py

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Car(models.Model):
    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django_admin_multiple_choice_list_filter.list_filters import MultipleChoiceListFilter
from .models import Car

class CarModelListFilter(MultipleChoiceListFilter):
    title = 'Car Model'
    parameter_name = 'car_model__in'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return CarModel.objects.values_list('pk', 'name')

class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('car_model',)
    list_filter = (CarModelListFilter,)

admin.site.register(Car, CarAdmin)
```